# Redux thunk not working with Axios & async/await

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, axios, redux-thunk

I am having a consistent problem when passing additional parameters to a thunk in redux using react. I am using `applyMiddleware(thunkMiddleware)` in the redux store.

I have a version of the code that works fine with axios.get for retrieving all records in the DB. This works great:

```
export async function fetchCollection(dispatch, getState) {
    return await axios
        .get(apiAddress + "/collections")
        .then(response => {
            dispatch({
                type: 'collectionLoaded',
                payload: response.data,
            })
        })

}
```

However when I try to modify this function so I can eventually pass in a variable and then return a thunk, I get nothing. The below is essentially copy and paste from the redux website, but does not work. I am running the function on page load to populate the state. This does not ping my backend server and the `dispatch` does not seem to run (the state is never updated in redux dev tools).

```
export function fetchCollection() {

    console.log("api: ", apiAddress + "/collections")

    return async function fetchCollectionThunk(dispatch, getState) {
        await axios
            .get(apiAddress + "/collections")
            .then(response => {
                dispatch({
                    type: 'collectionLoaded',
                    payload: response.data,
                })
            })
    }
}
```

My plan with the second function is to pass in the user ID so that I can request just the relevant data back from the API. The `console.log` I threw in does run, but nothing else. If I put a `console.log` in the `.then` function, it does not run.

Left out catch/error handling for simplicity, however the first code block runs without.

Not sure if I'm missing something or maybe I'm crazy. I had this issue once before with axios & redux and wasn't able to figure out the cause. Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT:**

In response to a few questions:

The action is being dispatched on the initial load. For development, I am using it to populate the state upfront. Eventually, there will be some more layers of complexity involved, but need to get this working first. Here is where the action is being dispatched:

**Index.js**

```
store.dispatch(fetchCollection)


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <App />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: When you use `then` you don't need `async/await`. Also, how are you dispatching that thunk action?

Comment: how are you calling `fetchCollection` function, can you please share the component code along with how it's connected to redux and all

Comment: Can you provide a link to the react-redux source documentation that has code examples like what you are trying to use? They seem very odd. Typically you'd write an asynchronous action creator that returns a function that simply consumes the `dispatch` object, i.e. `const myAsyncAction = (arg1, arg2,...) => dispatch => { .... }`.

Comment: @DrewReese answer seems good! You could also have a look at [createAsyncThunk](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk) from [redux-toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/)

Comment: Thanks for replies everyone! apokryfos and GulamHussain, I will edit my post above with responses. @Drew Reese, here is the link to the Redux tutorial where they do essentially the same thing (granted with fetch rather than Axios): [Redux Fundamentals](https://redux.js.org/tutorials/fundamentals/part-6-async-logic#saving-todo-items)

Comment: Ok, I see. Well two things come to mind: (1) have you setup/configured your redux store correctly, i.e. does it have the thunk middleware added to it to recognize actions that are functions instead of objects, and (2) are you dispatching the actions correctly in your UI code? Can you update your question to address both these questions?

Comment: You need to invoke your action creator so it returns either the action object or the thunk, i.e. `store.dispatch(fetchCollection())`, and if your action creator accepted parameters, `store.dispatch(fetchCollection(...args))`.

Comment: @DrewReese you last comment did the trick! I needed to actually *call* the function to get the return. Duh. Thank you!!!

Comment: No worries. Since resolved I'm voting to close as "unreproducible or caused by typo". Cheers and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved thanks to @DrewReese. The issue with my above code was that when I was call the actioned the action in index.js, I was passing in the wrapper function (fetchCollection) rather than executing it and passing in the return.

Now the action dispatch looks like this:

```
store.dispatch(fetchCollection())
```

which works as expected.

Thanks all!